# Tkinter - Linking buttons to different scripts

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am exploring GUI's at the moment. What I want is to have a GUI with a 2 buttons and I want each of the buttons to run a separate python script when clicked.
I have outlined my code below (the first button runs just fine but I am having issues with the second button.

**Error Message when I choose the second button:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
```

**Code:**

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
master = Tk()



def First_Scriptcallback():
    exec(open(r'Desktop\Automation\First_Script.py').read())


def second_Scriptcallback():
    exec(open(r'Desktop\Automation\Second_Script.py').read())


#master.title("Test GUI")
#canvas = tk.Canvas(master, height=300, width = 400)
#canvas.pack()

firstButton = Button(master, text="Run first script", command=First_Scriptcallback)
firstButton.pack()

secondButton = Button(master, text="Run second script", command=second_Scriptcallback)
secondButton.pack()


mainloop()
```

Thanks

Comment: what exactly are You running in those other scripts, also this is certainly not the best way of doing this, I would suggest instead either import the scripts (`from module import class, function, variable, etc`) or run them with terminal (if You have windows You can use `os.system('cd path\to\file\directory')` and in the next line `os.system('python file.py')` first You need to `import os`, one drawback is that the first script will stop responding because it is executing this)

Comment: Hi @matiss, Thanks for your response. What the other scripts do is open up another Tkinter GUI which asks the user to select a file, the script then manipulates the file and exports an excel sheet. There is a bit of work gone into these "other scripts" so if there is a way to create a GUI with 2 buttons that executes the other python files that would be fantasic

Comment: ok, but this is certainly not the way, if You have those other two scripts in the same directory or in a subdirectory You can import them (I won't be able to explain this as well as maybe some tutorial on youtube or just search google): `from directory.module import class, function, variable, etc` and then execute that in current script, also maybe just replacing `exec()` and all that with `import dir.module` or `import module` (depending on the structure) and it may execute them, or use cmd as mentioned above

Comment: @matiiss Okay perfect thanks. I'll have a look into what you mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @matiiss suggested importing the other scripts into your program can help and it can be done like this,

```
import First_Script as first
import Second_Script as second

from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
master = Tk()



def First_Scriptcallback():
    first.function_name()#here you must create functions in first_script to call in this main script


def second_Scriptcallback():
    second.function_name()


#master.title("Test GUI")
#canvas = tk.Canvas(master, height=300, width = 400)
#canvas.pack()

firstButton = Button(master, text="Run first script", command=First_Scriptcallback)
#command=first.function_name
#we can also directly call an function using above command,but sometimes there are problems related to this approch
firstButton.pack()

secondButton = Button(master, text="Run second script", command=second_Scriptcallback)
#command=second.function_name
secondButton.pack()


mainloop()
```

here for this example the scripts and the program must be in same directory.

Comment: Thank you, I was just about to add an answer to this similar to what you have outlined above. thanks